# Typescript adding single item to object array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert the following function to accept lines entered into an input field.  It works fine if there are multiple lines, I'm reading the entries into an array if there is a line break "\n", but I can't figure out how to get it to format a single entry without the line break as an array item:

```
  const obj = {};
  Object.keys(value).map(function(data) {
    if (data !== 'submit') {
      const val: string = value[data].toString();
      let result = val;
      // this is accounting for line breaks
      if (val.indexOf('\n') > 0) {

        //multiple lines, being added into array correctly 
        result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(val.split('\n')));

      } else {

        //problem is here, need result as a single item in an array
        result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(val));
      }
      obj[data] = result;
    }
  });
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide an example input and expected output.

Comment: This code looks really shady. What are you trying to do? I'm sure there is an easier way in the end? Provide us the user story.

Comment: It's a multi line text box that I'm using to dynamically generate some input fields.  If there are entries with a line break, they're parsed into result as an array which gets passed to a service.

Answer (score 2):

May be you need to convert the val to an array.
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([val]));

Comment: Yup, that's what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Will this work? wrapping single item in an array with []

```
const obj = {};
      Object.keys(value).map(function(data) {
            if (data !== 'submit') {
                const val: string = value[data].toString();
                let result = val;
                // this is accounting for line breaks
                if (val.indexOf('\n') > 0) {
                    //multiple lines, being added into array correctly 
                    result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(val.split('\n')));
                } else {
                    //problem is here, need result as a single item in an array
                    result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([val]));
                }
            obj[data] = result;
      }
  });
```